# Laravel route giving 403 error but duplicate route is fine

Tags: laravel, xampp

Getting very confused.  I returned to my code yesterday after a meeting and I was getting a 403 error on a page that I was not before.  Nothing (that I know of) has changed.  What makes this odder (in my view) is that I duplicated the route with a slight append and that works fine:

```
Route::get('/flexbot2', 'FlexController@flexbot')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/flexbot', 'FlexController@flexbot')->middleware('auth');
```

So the top route works, the bottom one fails.  I'm using xampp, windows 10, laravel 6.  It also works perfectly well in production, this is purely a local issue.  Everything I look at refers to either vhost config or htaccess, but that doesn't seem relevant here as everything was working and now isn't.  I'm still pretty new to all of this, so I may be missing something very obvious.

Thanks, sorry if this duplicates but my searching hasn't returned any results.

Comment: sorry, should be a "slight" amend not a sight one.

Comment: You can always edit your question. :)

Comment: Hah thanks, done.  Couldn't see that button there.

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list` to see what routes are registered.

Comment: Bad formatting, apologies:| GET|HEAD | flexbot                             |                  | App\Http\Controllers\FlexController@flexbot
           | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD | flexbot2                            |                  | App\Http\Controllers\FlexController@flexbot

Comment: Please edit your post to include entire web.php 